# React Slide Routes shows findDOMNode warning

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, react-router, react-transition-group

I tried to use React Slide Routes library to give some sliding effect for my router but I'm getting this error whenever I change the route. like clicking on a link.

*react_devtools_backend.js:4026*

```
     *Warning: findDOMNode is deprecated in StrictMode. findDOMNode was passed an instance of Transition which is inside StrictMode. Instead, add a ref directly to the element you want to reference*
```

I checked where this error comes from, and I think React Slide Routes can't work with material-UI library I use.

here is where the error comes from:

[image]

I can disable strict mode by removing it from `index.js` but it will hide the problem. how can I solve this problem?

`Router.js`

```
  <SlideRoutes
      pathList={["/", "/login", "/signup", "/main", "/signAuth", "*"]}
    >
      <Route element={<ProfileDrawer />}>
        <Route path="/main" element={<Mainpage />} />
      </Route>
      <Route index path="/" element={<Login />} />
      <Route path="/Login" element={<Login />} />
      <Route
        path="/Signup"
        element={
          <React.Suspense fallback={<LazyLoader />}>
            <Signup />
          </React.Suspense>
        }
      />
      <Route path="/signAuth" element={<Verification />} />
      <Route path="*" element={<NotFound />} />
    </SlideRoutes>
```

`index.js`:

```
<React.StrictMode>
    <BrowserRouter>
      <StyledEngineProvider injectFirst>
        <Provider store={store}>
          <App />
        </Provider>
      </StyledEngineProvider>
    </BrowserRouter>
  </React.StrictMode>
```

I tried to add nodeRef as there was similar question about react bootstrap here. but it didn't work

I use latest version of MUI

Comment: It's ***just*** a warning. You can safely ignore it until the library maintainers use something *other than* `findDOMNode`. You could also fork the repo and fix it yourself, they may appreciate a pull request.

Comment: @DrewReese can't we fix it ourselves? in React bootstrap question here, they were adding `nodeRef` but I have no idea how we can do it for `react-slide-route`

Comment: Looks like there's an [open](https://github.com/nanxiaobei/react-slide-routes/issues/17) issue for it, and at least one [closed](https://github.com/nanxiaobei/react-slide-routes/issues/2) that appears to be pretty informative.

Comment: @DrewReese I think they still didn't fix this issue. well. I think I should wait

Comment: It's *almost always* 3rd-party code, so the options are basically (1) live with and ignore it, (2) uninstall the package and look for something else, (3) fork some repos and try to fix it yourself.